# Check the value of a text input field with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a website where the log ins are screen names. On the create user form I want to be able to have ajax check if a screen name exists already as it is typed into the form.

**This is the HTML form input field**

```
<label for="screenName">Screen Name:
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="screenName" id="screenName" size="28" required>
<div class="screenNameError"></div>
```

A message should be displayed in the `<div class="screenNameError"></div>`line if the username matches the database.

**This is my Jquery code for this.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('#screenName').length > 0){

    var screenName = $("input").keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        return value;
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:  'screenNameCheck.php',
        data: 'Screen_Name=' + screenName,

        success: function (r) {
            $('.screenNameError').html(r);
        }
    })

}
```

});

**This is the PHP file that gets called to make the DB query**

```
$screenName = $_POST['Screen_Name'];

$screenNameSQL = "SELECT Screen_Name FROM Users WHERE Screen_Name = '$screenName'";
$result = $my_dbhandle->query($screenNameSQL); //Query database
$numResults = $result->num_rows; //Count number of results

$resultCount = intval($numResults);

if($resultCount > 0){
    echo "The username entered already exists. Please a different user name.";
}
```

For some reason my Jquery is not firing when I type the username in the form :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) You have SQL injection vulnerability 2) Check javascript console of your browser and see if you have any errors

Comment: I know that I need to take care of SQL injection. I haven't gotten to it, but it's on my "to do" list. The console was giving me errors but I cleared them all.

Comment: You shouldn't clear error logs, they are there for you to read them to understand the issue

Comment: @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9 I meant that I cleared them by resolving them in changing up my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your jQuery to this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#screenName').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'screenNameCheck.php',
      data: 'Screen_Name=' + value,
      success: function(r) {
        $('.screenNameError').html(r);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

However you probably want to minimise the number of ajax requests being made so I would advise putting your ajax request into a `setTimeout` functon and clearing it with each subsequent keypress. -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ajaxRequest;
  $('#screenName').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    clearTimeout(ajaxRequest);
    ajaxRequest = setTimeout(function(sn) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'screenNameCheck.php',
        data: 'Screen_Name=' + value,
        success: function(r) {
          $('.screenNameError').html(r);
        }
      });
    }, 500, value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sadly you can only mark one response as the answer because @Alexis helped me a lot. But your code worked very well, especially the time out! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Well that's what up votes are for, glad you got all the help you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event  on keyup like this :

**Edit**

```
$("#screenName").on("keyup",function(){
  var screenName=$(this).val();

if(screenName!='')
{
 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:  'screenNameCheck.php',
        data: 'Screen_Name=' + screenName,

        success: function (r) {
            $('.screenNameError').html(r);
        }
    })
}
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp1on50m/)

Comment: I tried your code both inside the (document).ready function and by itself and it didn't work. :/

Comment: Try to add an alert in the if statement... and look at the screenName

Comment: Ok, I tried it and the alert didn't show up. So it must be that the keyup is not firing?

Comment: Which version of Jquery and which brower do you use ?

Comment: I am calling this version in the header file <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> and right now I am on Chrome. Let me try Firefox.

Comment: Use a newest version, here is a test of my example : https://jsfiddle.net/dp1on50m/

Comment: I found out what it was. I needed to move the Jquery code to the bottom of the page. So it shows me the alert now. The only thing now is that it isn't returning the results from the php file.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#screenName').length > 0){
```

You should change it with

```
if ($('#screenName').val().length > 0){
```

OR

```
var name = $('#screenName').val();
if(name.length >0) {...
```

not sure about the syntax...

Comment: ID #screenName is the ID to the input field. Class .screenNameError is the class to the div where the error message should appear.

Comment: yeah, i realised that and changed, thanks @AbrahamA.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call should be inside the keyup handler.